# Passing Textbox Value to another page via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I need to accomplish the follow:

1. allow user to input data into a textbox attribute of form/input element
2. after the user inputs the data and presses enter, the user is then directed to another page where the entered data is display

I have the following:
(would prefer to work with JS and HTML without involving PHP)

Index Page:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Index Page </title>
    </head>

    <body>

        <form>
            <input id = "userInput" type = "textbox" name = "firstName">
        </form>

        <script>
        var inputTest = document.getElementById('userInput').value;
        localStorage.setItem( 'objectToPass', inputTest );
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Redirect Page:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title> Redirect Page </title>
  </head>

  <body>

    <script>
      var inputTest = localStorage['objectToPass'];
      localStorage.removeItem( 'objectToPass' ); // Clear the localStorage
      var displayData = inputTest;
      alert('Inserted Data' + inputTest);
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

I am unable to get this to work, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: you need to save the data, once the form submitted. See [this](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onsubmit.asp).

Comment: @Aᴍɪʀ The OP is saving the data... in `localStorage`.

Comment: Can you explain "not getting this to work"? Are you getting an error? What do you get?

Comment: @ScottMarcus I know, but it should save it when the form is submitted, or when the input changes.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing 2 things:

1. You'll want to get the textbox value when the form is submitted. Right now, you are attempting to get the value as soon as the page loads, which (at that point) won't contain a value.
2. Second, you don't seem to be doing any redirect to the second page.

**Input page:**

Index Page

```
<body>

    <form id="frmTest">
        <input id = "userInput" type = "textbox" name = "firstName">
    </form>

    <script>
      // Get a reference to the form so that we can set up an event handler
      // for its submit event
      var form = document.getElementById("frmTest");

      // Now, set up a submit event handler for the form
      form.addEventListener("submit", function(){

        // Only when the form has been submitted do you want the textbox value
        var inputTest = document.getElementById('userInput').value;
        localStorage.setItem( 'objectToPass', inputTest );

        window.location = "NEW URL";

      });

    </script>

</body>
```

**Redirect Page:**

Redirect Page

```
<script>
  var inputTest = localStorage.getItem('objectToPass');
  var displayData = inputTest;
  alert('Inserted Data' + inputTest);

  localStorage.removeItem( 'objectToPass' ); // Clear the localStorage

</script>
```

Comment: There is no problem with removing localStorage item right after getting it right? You din't change the order in intentionally? If there is can you explain.

Comment: There is no problem doing it that way, but it makes more logical sense and is better for scale if you wait until you've done all your work with the value before removing it. This way, additional lines could be inserted that work with `localStorage` without the progression becoming an issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are storing the value in the localStorage before the user inputs any data in the input field hence empty value is stored.

You can do this to listen to **Enter** keypress before reading the value from input field.

```
var inputTest = document.getElementById('userInput');

inputTest.addEventListener('keypress',function(key){  // Enter key Press Listener
     key.which = key.which || key.keyCode;
     if(key.which == 13) {
         store_data();
     }
});
```

Also you can add a click listener to the button to listen for click and fetch the value from the input field.

```
var inputTest = document.getElementById('userInput');
var add = document.getElementById('add');

add.addEventListener('click',function(e){
  store_data();
});
```

You can store data like this

```
function store_data(){ // Store value from input field to local store
   localStorage.setItem( 'objectToPass', inputTest.value);
}
```

Here is an Example: https://n-demo.000webhostapp.com/

**[index.html](https://n-demo.000webhostapp.com)**

[Click here](https://n-demo.000webhostapp.com) to set a value to local storage and on submit you will be redirected 
to  [redirect.html](https://n-demo.000webhostapp.com/redirect.html)

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title> Index Page </title>
  </head>

 <body>

 <form action="/redirect.html">
    <input id = "userInput" type = "textbox" name = "firstName">
    <button id='add'>Add to local storage</button>
 </form>

 </body>

 <script>
    var inputTest = document.getElementById('userInput');

    document.getElementById('add').addEventListener('click',store_data);  //Button Click Listener.

    inputTest.addEventListener('keypress',function(key){  // Enter key Press Listener
        key.which = key.which || key.keyCode;
        if(key.which == 13) {
            store_data();
        }
    });

    function store_data(){ // Store value from input field to local store
        localStorage.setItem( 'objectToPass', inputTest.value);
    }
 </script>
</html>
```

**[redirect.html](https://n-demo.000webhostapp.com/redirect.html)**

It fetch data from local storage and alerts the value.
On fetch we removed the data from the local storage `localStorage.removeItem( 'objectToPass' );`

If you go to `redirect.html` before the `index.html` the data will be `undefined`.

**Note: You can read the local storage only if the redirected page is on the same domain.**

if a value is set from `<yor-domain>/index.html` 
then only pages like  `<your-domain>/<some-page>` can read the storage values.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title> Redirect Page </title>
  </head>

  <body>

  <h1>In Redirected Page</h1>

  <script>
      var inputTest = localStorage['objectToPass'];
      localStorage.removeItem( 'objectToPass' ); // Clear the localStorage

      alert('Inserted Data ' + inputTest);
  </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

You actually accomplish a big portion of what you need to do. You only need to add your onsubmit function;

```
<form onsubmit="submitHandler()">
    <input id = "userInput" type = "textbox" name = "firstName">
</form>

<script>
function submitHandler(){
var inputTest = document.getElementById('userInput').value;
localStorage.setItem( 'objectToPass', inputTest );
// now redirect the page.
window.location.href = "redirect.html";
}
</script>
```

That's all.

---

See onsubmit event listener: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onsubmit.asp

Comment: Please don't use or adivse `on` event handling properties as they are outdated, create spaghetti code, cause anonymous global event wrapper functions to be created and don't follow W3C DOM Event standards. Also, don't provide W3Schools as references as much of their information is wrong or out of date. Use MDN instead.

Comment: Do use w3schools to guide beginners (it is a really good website to learn) but leave a note saying that it might not follow the best practices and may be outdated.

Comment: I would advise against W3 Schools from the get go. MDN is the authoritative source. Why send someone to a source that may provide incorrect or out of date information that they have no way of knowing?

Comment: Also MDN does not have ads :)